# What does the woman know when she says 后来才知道 (hòulái cái zhīdào)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

(*Edit*: It looks like I originally excluded some important content, so I expanded the snippet below.)

This question is about 后来才知道 in the following sentence, where a woman describes her developing relationship with a man:

> 起初我是不同意的，可是他很会表现，不仅对我好，对我父母也极尽照顾，有一次为了帮我送父亲进医院，冒着大雨开车去省城，**后来才知道**，他为了帮我，把6岁大的儿子一个人锁在家里整整一夜，彻底感动了我，交往不到一年，我们结婚了。
>   <sub>[嫁给离婚带孩子的男人 我的生活只剩下两个字](http://www.guaixun.com/bdnews/content_214083_1.html), guaixun.com</sub>

(The second part was part of my earlier question [Did the man lock up his 6-year old son at home overnight? (把6岁大的儿子一个人锁在家里整整一夜)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29680).)

I translate this to something like:

> At first, I did not agree, but he performs well [i.e., impressed me], not only did he treat me well, he did his best to look after my parents, one time to help me admit my father to a hospital, he braved the rain and drove to the provincial capital, **afterwards only then I knew**, to help me, he took his 6-year old son and locked him in the house by himself for the whole night, which thoroughly touched me, and being in contact for less than a year, we married.

Perhaps this means that is when she knew she was in love with him.  Or maybe it means she only found out the man about helping her father after he was in hospital.  I'm not sure.

**Question**: What does the woman know when she says 后来才知道?

Comment: The fact that the man locked up his son. She didn't know that when the man helped her to send her father to the hospital. She knew the fact afterwards.

Comment: Encounter a translation,
后来我才知道篮球社的助理就是每天给他们捡球，打扫，送水，送毛巾的人。
It wasn’t until afterwards that I found out my job was to help them pick up the balls, sweep, deliver water and towels on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what the woman know afterwards is he locked his six-year-old son in the house for a whole night, just for taking her father to the hospital. Beacuase it is dangerous that locked a child in the house about a whole night, so the woman was  thoroughly touched.

Answer (score 1):

According to the description, the woman may know he do his best to look after her parents, and one day he braved the rain and drove her father to the hospital. Maybe the woman did not know who take her father to the hospital at first. But she got the information form other channel later, or somebody told her it was the man took her father to the hospital. 
There maybe other thing the woman know afterwards. But you did not write out the ellipsis of "后来才知道。。。"。 So, maybe it is the ellpsis that the woman know afterwards.

Comment: I edited to include the rest of the sentence (after the ellipsis).

Answer (score 1):

> What does the woman know when she says 后来才知道?
>
> 起初我是不同意的，可是他很会表现，不仅对我好，对我父母也极尽照顾，有一次为了帮我送父亲进医院，冒着大雨开车去省城，后来才知道，**他为了帮我，把6岁大的儿子一个人锁在家里整整一夜**，彻底感动了我，交往不到一年，我们结婚了

The things she knew afterwards is  他为了帮我，把6岁大的儿子一个人锁在家里整整一夜. I think the punctuation of the paragraph is not that good, all commas out there, which might cause some confusion especially to non-native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

A natural translation of this to English would be "I only found out later that...". It's referring to the following sentence about locking the child in the room.

Answer (score 1):

> **后来才知道**

It usually used to indicate that "some extra information" is going to be revealed

It revealed the fact that "他为了帮我，把6岁大的儿子一个人锁在家里整整一夜".

Answer (score 0):

起初我是不同意的，
At first I wasn't interested,
可是他很会表现，
however, he is really attentive, gallant (献殷勤)
不仅对我好，
(he is) not only good to me
对我父母也极尽照顾，
but also takes extremely good care of my parents
有一次为了帮我送父亲进医院，
one time, in order to help me get my father to hospital,
冒着大雨开车去省城，
he braved the heavy rain and drove to the provincial capital.
后来才知道，
it was only after that that I found out,
他为了帮我，
in order to help me,
把6岁大的儿子一个人锁在家里整整一夜，
he locked his 6 year old son all alone in his house the whole night,
彻底感动了我，交往不到一年，我们结婚了。
I was very moved, so we got married, although we had only known each other less than a year.

(Watch out for a guy who locks up his 6 year old son alone all night! Someone like that is capable of anything!)